# Is there an embeddable, C# version of Emmet?

Tags: emmet

Is there an Emmet API in C#?  *I am not talking about text expansion in Visual Studio*.  What I want is to be able to use Emmet at runtime in a C# application, like this:

```
var shorthand = "div>ul>li";
var html = Emmet.Transform(shorthand);  // Note: this line is currently imaginary...
```

The `html` variable would then contain a string:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Again, I want to embed an Emmet engine in a C# application and dynamically transform strings at runtime.  I do not want the Visual Studio plugin.  (I don't mean to be pedantic about that, but that seems to be the de facto answer for every question about Emmet and C#...)

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Emmet is a plugin for multiple tools and I don't see any library for it being made available by the developers so far. So, I guess, no would be the answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ManoDestra: I ended up writing my own.  See the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote one:

[Nemmet: "Not Emmet." An HTML expander in C#.](https://github.com/deanebarker/nemmet)

Comment: Nice. Necessity is the mother of invention :)